# Register msjro.dll and msadox.dll on Win 7

Tags: dll, regsvr32

I know there are already two DLLs registered on Win7 x64.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msadox.dll
```

I'm still trying to put my own DLLs into system folder (e.g. C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for WIN7 x64), and then use regsvr32 to register the DLL files.

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjro.dll
```

However, I am failed to do so. Can anyone teach me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to unregister old ones and then try to register yours (you can place them other place not system folder)

Comment: I did try this, but it showed the following error:
http://s12.postimg.org/dxxc8tsgb/error.png

Comment: How you wrote that dll? What language have you used? Are you sure that your dll is working correctly?

Comment: I didn't edit these two DLLs, I just tried to put a different version of the DLLs. Those two DLLs are copied from Win XP and they function well in Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register it using cmd. If your using win 7 above please run cmd in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to check that in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 you have msdart.dll version 2.81.1117.0 (you can copy and paste this dll from a xp os from dir c:\Windows\system32). Gianni